# Find and replace with asterisk (*) in vim

Tags: vim, replace

I have a text file, which lists file names in a directory (excerpt below). The item names are the f followed 3-digit numbers.

```
 771M Jan 22 02:35 f186
 1.2G Jan 22 02:35 f172
 771M Jan 22 02:36 f206
 771M Jan 22 02:37 f151
 771M Jan 22 02:37 f029
 1.2G Jan 22 02:38 f162
 771M Jan 22 02:40 f168
 1.2G Jan 22 02:42 f244
...
```

I would like to have a list of **only** the 3-digit numbers. Therefore, I need to repalce the previous columns by "nothing". Since the content of the previous columns is different for each line, I would use an asterisk, and the following approach seemed logic for me in VIM:

```
:%s/*f/
```

where I replace everything followed by an f by nothing.

Why doesn't this work? How do I do this in VIM?

Comment: Didn't know it existed. Good point!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vim uses regex and, in regex, an asterisk is actually a quantifier.

What you want is this:

```
:%s/.*f/
```

the `.` character means any character, and the `*` means any number of `.`s. So, the combination `.*` matches essentially anything, which is what you were looking for.

Regexes are simultaneously the most useful and annoying things I have ever learned, so I would recommend getting familiar with them.

Comment: You can drop the trailing `/`